# WinAPI access to 24-bit color on Windows console

Tags: winapi, windows-10, windows-console

Recent Windows 10 builds [added 24-bit RGB color support to the console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/). Demo screenshots feature Linux scripts that presumably use ISO terminal control codes to change colors.

Is there a concomitant addition to [Windows console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) to allow access to all these colors without using control sequences, or is such an API known to be planned for a future release?

Comment: Speculation on API design by a third party is not really on-topic.

Comment: Typical MS fashion would be to not backport to the old API. Vista added some new functions but 99% of that API has not changed since NT4.

Comment: I did not mean to ask for speculation but confirmed knowledge. Edited question to clarify wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporters have already responded to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1118), They're not planning on expanding the Win32 API surface for this feature. Every function added to the Console API just creates another point of incompatibility with linux terminal applications.

If you want to use the new color support in your application, you'll have to use VT sequences. Support can be enabled with `SetConsoleMode`(see [Output Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#Output_Sequences))

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: the mode itself is a point of incompatibility. the mode doesnt say how deep colors are, 8-bits or 16-bits or 24-bits or... it only says that system has newer APIs.